# How do I send multiple messages as my source

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I'm just trying out this sample stream that currently has a single TextMessage as a source:

```
 // print each incoming strict text message
    val printSink: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
      Sink.foreach {
        case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
          println(message.text)
        case _ =>
        // ignore other message types
      }

    val helloSource: Source[Message, NotUsed] =
      Source.single(TextMessage("hello world!"))

    // the Future[Done] is the materialized value of Sink.foreach
    // and it is completed when the stream completes
    val flow: Flow[Message, Message, Future[Done]] =
      Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(printSink, helloSource)(Keep.left)
```

I want to send 2 messages, so I tried this:

```
val source1 = Source.single(TextMessage("hello"))
val source2 = Source.single(TextMessage("world"))

val helloSource: Source[Message, NotUsed] =
  Source.combine(source2)
```

But I get this error:

```
 polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : [U](strategy: Int => akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.UniformFanInShape[akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.TextMessage.Strict,U],akka.NotUsed]): akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[U,akka.NotUsed]
[error]  required: akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.Message,akka.NotUsed]
[error]       Source.combine(source1, source2)
[error]                     ^
[error] one error found
```

What exactly should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Source.combine`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/combine.html) is a flexible way to combine multiple sources, and you  need to specify a strategy for combining them, as described in the linked documentation.

In this case, where you want to have one finite source be followed by another, you can use the [`Concat`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.6/akka/stream/scaladsl/Concat.html) strategy.

```
val helloSource: Source[Message, NotUsed] =
  Source.combine(source1, source2)(Concat(_))
```

As a simpler alternative, you can use the [`concat`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/concat.html) method on the first source:

```
val helloSource: Source[Message, NotUsed] =
  source1.concat(source2)
```

However, for this example, where you have a fixed set of hardcoded elements, it's even simpler to avoid the creation of multiple sources and create only a single source from an `Iterable` with [`Source.apply`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/from.html):

```
val helloSource: Source[Message, NotUsed] =
  Source(Seq(TextMessage("hello"), TextMessage("world")))
```